# I am getting error 500 and null pointer exception

Tags: java, forms, jsp

I am making project on online examination in java.
I am facing a problem.

On starting base I have 15 questions in my database and I am fetching those sequentially.
The problem is that if I attempt all the answers I get the results otherwise I get `error 500` and `NullPointerException`. The questions are multiple choice. Every question has four options. If I don't attempt all the questions then I get the above error.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%
    String st[] = new String[20];
    String ans[] = new String[20];
    int k=0;
    //int length = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("length").toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        st[i] = request.getParameter("radio" + j);
        System.out.println(st[i]);
    }
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "root", "root");
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select ANS from ANSWERS order by ID");
    //String ans = "";
    int t;
    while (rs.next()) {

        ans[k] = rs.getString("ans");
        k++;
        System.out.println(ans[k]);
    }

    int count = 0;
    //String answers[] = ans.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if (st[i].equals(ans[i])) {
            count++;
        }

    }
    out.println("Your " + count + " answers are correct");
%>
```

Comment: You mean if you dont attempt all the questions, then you are getting the error?

Comment: Use break points in your code and see at which line the errors pop's up

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception) to get an idea what your Null pointer exception meant

Comment: What does the NullPointerException say? That usually gives some hint to where the unexpected Null is.

Comment: Code blocks in JSP makes me cringe. Database code in a JSP makes me cry.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your answers are simply not submitted back with your request. If the radio group for a question does not have a selected value, that radio group is not going to be part of the POST request that you are processing after the form submission.

That is why you get the Null pointer exception in the first place.
I cannot runt your example above, but i assume that the error is happening in the comparison line at the end of your example:

```
if (st[i].equals(ans[i])) {
```

**Update**
For a quick fix, just switch the evaluated values: `st[i].equals(ans[i])` to `ans[i].equals(st[i])`. That way you can always do a equals against null and get the correct count.

Comment: Never write logic that assumes certain parameter will or will not be included from the client. Handle the Null scenario on the server instead.

Comment: @pap you are right about that. i just wanted to throw a quick fix to the problem, which is already a mess, and that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your code you're initializing your `st[]` with `request.getParameter("radio" + j);` This might come as null. As per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) for `getParameter()`:

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the
>   parameter does not exist.

So when you try to execute this following piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    if (st[i].equals(ans[i])) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

There is a chance that `st[i]` is in fact `null`. This might *possibly* be a reason for the `NullPointerException` in your code

Answer (score 0):

You should be enclosing your logic in try catch and in finally handle the SQL exception for connection, rs (in separate try catch blocks)
Also, try lloking at the stack trace, as to which line gives the null pointer exception